# Can someone point me to gentoo for powermac g5 quad?

Tags: gentoo, powerpc

I am unsure which download is most useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerMac G5 is a "New World" Mac, and it is 64bit only. So you need this image:

http://distfiles.gentoo.org/releases/ppc/autobuilds/20150115/stage3-ppc64-64ul-20150115.tar.bz2

Side note:

If it's the Gentoo experience you are looking for, obviously you're on the right track. If you are just trying to get a Mac up and running on Linux, I strongly recommend http://debian.org. I'm not usually a Debian user, but I run Linux on a lot of Macs (my main laptop is an iBook G4) and I find that Debian is remarkably good at managing the quirks of Apple hardware. No bias; just what I have found from running Linux on discarded Apple hardware over the past several years.

Comment: Tried debian and it failed spent hours of my time trying to get the boot to even work and I still have my mac sitting without a working os on it other than debian because it failed...

Comment: what about fedora core?